# Get Number of customers who have done transaction on 1st Anniversary week and soo on - SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a transaction table which contains purchase history of all the customers. I want to find out the number of customers who have have purchased within a week(7 days) of their 1st purchase anniversary(Using Min(Bill_Date))

```
Customer_Id   Bill_Date
   1          2020-01-23
   1          2021-01-28
   2          2020-09-01
   2          2021-09-07
   3          2020-03-01
```

So the expected output:

> The No of customers who have purchased with a week of their 1st
> purchase anniversary is : 3

I am stuck after this step

```
with CTE As
(Select customer_id,Bill_Date from
(Select Customer_id,Bill_Date,Dense_Rank() over(partition by Customer_id order by Bill_Date)r1 from CDM_Bill_Details)t1
where t1.r1=1
group by customer_id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use exists logic here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, MIN(Bill_Date) OVER (PARTITION BY Customer_Id) Min_Bill_Date
    FROM CDM_Bill_Details
)

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Customer_Id) AS cnt
FROM
(
    SELECT Customer_Id
    FROM cte
    WHERE Bill_Date > Min_Bill_Date AND
          DATEDIFF(Bill_Date - interval 1 year, Min_Bill_Date) <= 7
) t;
```

The above `WHERE` clause compares a bill date other than the first one against the first bill date by subtracting one year, then asserting that this subsequent purchase is plus or minus 7 days from the first purchase.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply, But the following query also considers 7 days backwards also

Comment: @Harishreddy I have edited the logic to only allow up to a forward 7 days.  This requirement was not clear from reading your question.

Comment: Customer having transactions on the following days are also considered when i ran the query in the database                                                                          
 2017-04-28,                                                                                                                   
 2018-02-27                                                                                                                         
 2018-04-26